# How to change color of ellipse when new ellipse is draw in a timer in C#

Tags: c#, drawing, paint, ellipse

I have a function which is drawing an ellipse. I want to make the previously drawn ellipse invisible by changing its color as the same color of its background when a new ellipse is drawn by changing the form size.

This is my function in my class:

```
class ClassClock
{
    public static void drawClock(Point m, int s, Form frm, Color myColor) 
    {
        Graphics paper = frm.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(myColor);

        int w = frm.ClientSize.Width;
        int h = frm.ClientSize.Height;
        m = new Point(w / 2, h / 2);
        s = Math.Min(w, h) / 2;

        paper.DrawEllipse(myPen, m.X - s, m.Y - s, s * 2, s * 2);
    }
}
```

and this is my timer:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassClock.drawClock(m, s, this, this.BackColor);
    ClassClock.drawClock(m, s, this, Color.Black);
}
```

Can someone help me find a solution to this?

Comment: You'll have to have a reference to the old ellipse in order to do anything with it.

Comment: You need to erase the old ellipse and draw the new ellipse in your `Paint` event handler, not in your `Tick`. Your `Tick` handler should invalidate the old and new ellipse regions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `CreateGraphics` like this.  Instead, override the `OnPaint` method of your form and do all your painting in that method.

Windows uses an immediate mode graphics system.  That means that once your ellipse is drawn, it's gone, save for the pixels currently on the screen.  If the window is minimized or another window is dragged across it, the ellipse will be gone and will have to be repainted.  That is what the `OnPaint` method is for.

Here's a simple form that changes the color of your circle when a button is clicked.  To run this code, you will need to add a button to the form and name it *btnChangeColor*.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Property to hold the current color.  This could be a private field also.
    public Color CurrentColor { get; set; } = Color.Red;

    //Used to generate a random number when the button is clicked.
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    //All painting of the form should be in this method.
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        //Use the graphics event provided to you in PaintEventArgs
        Graphics paper = e.Graphics;

        int w = this.ClientSize.Width;
        int h = this.ClientSize.Height;
        Point m = new Point(w / 2, h / 2);
        int s = Math.Min(w, h) / 2;

        //It is important to dispose of any pens you create
        using (Pen myPen = new Pen(CurrentColor))
        {
            paper.DrawEllipse(myPen, m.X - s, m.Y - s, s * 2, s * 2);
        }
    }

    //When the button is clicked, the `CurrentColor` property is set to a random
    //color and the form is refreshed to get it to repaint itself.
    private void btnChangeColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Change the current color
        CurrentColor = Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256), rnd.Next(0, 256));

        //Refresh the form so it repaints itself
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```